# Different CCLayer size depending on where it is referenced inside the block

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am pretty new to C++ and cocos2d-x, so the answer could be something very simple, but for the life of me I can't figure out why it's acting like this.

Below is a relevant snippet, modified/simplified version of `HelloWorldScene.cpp`:

```
bool PlayGame::init()
{
    if ( !Layer::init() ) return false;

    double startX = this->getBoundingBox().getMidX() / 3;
    double startY = this->getBoundingBox().size.height * 0.95;

    Sprite* sprite = Sprite::create( "sprite.png" );
    sprite->setPosition( startX, startY );
    this->addChild( sprite );

    return true;
}
```

Now my code works perfectly as intended, but if I were to define `startX` and `startY` *before* the line that checks if the `CCLayer` has initialized properly, they return `(0, 0)` instead of somehwere in the top left corner. My guess is that, before the line `if ( !Layer::init() )`, the `PlayGame` layer has not been initialized and therefore have a size of `0`.

But as far as I'm concerned, that line is only responsible for checking whether the layer has initialized without a problem, and the actual initialization is triggered by the `create()` method called inside the definition of the parent `CCScene`. So I thought the size of the layer should have been initialized anywhere inside the function block.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PlayGame::create()` function in `createScene()`, which would look something like this in your case

```
Scene* PlayGame::createScene()
{
    auto scene = Scene::create();
    auto layer = PlayGame::create();   // this one right here constructs the Layer and triggers PlayGame::init()
    scene->addChild(layer);

    return scene;
}
```

is responsible for calling your `PlayGame::init()` function. However, the static `Layer::init()`, which sets the content size, must be explicitly called before you set or get any `Layer`-related members in `init()`.

Here's the implementation of `Layer::init()` directly extracted from the library

```
bool Layer::init()
{
    Director * director = Director::getInstance();
    setContentSize(director->getWinSize());    // this is the line that needs to be executed before you set anything
    return true;
}
```